# Names with question marks

Tags: grammar, american-english, questions

If someone asks me about a person I don't know, can I say, for example?:

Hey, do you know Mark?
Mark? No, I don't. Who's he?

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I just wanna make sure about. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can because "Mark?" is an abbreviation of "Do I know mark?"

The question mark also tells a reader how to pronounce it. A question is asked with a rising intonation.

P.S. It's best not to use 'wanna' or 'gonna' in written English. You see those abbreviations in song lyrics and in text messages etc. but they are not recognised spellings and look uneducated in a serious discussion ;-)

Comment: unreMarkable.  (Why did Mark get downgraded?)